# Wordpress Multilingual absolute link

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, multilingual

I am working on a WordPress website, and need to add a multilingual plugin.

Here is my problem: I don't want any automatic translation, but flags that lead to absolute links, as every language will be on a different domain name.

I can't find any existing plugin that is doing this, and I can't make my own one as I don't have enough time and my PHP skills are low.

Do you think about a plugin I could use for this? Or a plugin I could download and modify?

Thank you.

Comment: try asking this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ stackoverflow is for programing/coding questions. wordpress.stackexchange. Is for everything WP related.

Answer (score 0):

[WPML](http://wpml.org/) allows you to use multiple domains for multiple languages. It is very reliable and offers many other possibilities.

They have a tutorial on their page: [Multilingual Site Network with Domain Mapping](http://wpml.org/documentation/essential-multilingual-plugins/multilingual-site-network-with-domain-mapping/).

Comment: I just found exactly what I was looking for, flags widget:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flags-widget/

Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: http://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/custom-language-switcher/